# Git add fails while merging

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches that I like to merge "A" and "B". So I did the following

```
git checkout A
git checkout -b AB
git merge B
```

No I have a conflict in file TestSequenceSchemaTest.cs that I also resolved using TortoiseMerge. After "Resolve Finished" I made a git status

```
schoetbi@P02016097 /s/sara_git ((24a2cd5...)|REBASE)
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   SARA.sln
#       modified:   src/Module.TestProgramAdmin/SARA.Modules.TPA.IpoFile.Test/Sara.Modules.TPA.IpoFile.Test.csproj
#       modified:   src/Module.TestProgramAdmin/Sara.Modules.TPA.IpoFile.Test/Sara.Modules.TPA.IpoFile.Test.csproj
#       modified:   src/Module.TestProgramAdmin/Sara.Modules.TPA.IpoFile.Test/TestSequenceSchemaTest.cs
#       renamed:    src/Platform.RT/Sara.Platform.RT.Components/MediatorComponent/SequenceGeneratorXml.cs.orig -> src/Pl
atform.RT/Sara.Platform.RT.Components/MediatorComponent/SequenceGeneratorXml.cs
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:      src/Module.TestProgramAdmin/SARA.Modules.TPA.IpoFile.Test/TestSequenceSchemaTest.cs
#
```

Now I tried git add

```
git add src/Module.TestProgramAdmin/SARA.Modules.TPA.IpoFile.Test/TestSequenceSchemaTest.cs
```

But now the file stays still in the "both modified:" section. What can I do now?

Comment: Does `git add` not say anything? No error message or anything?

Comment: @Dolda200: git add says not a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought not exactly required, but, are you sure you did the `git checkout` to a branch? As the git status says, you are `Not currently on any branch`. You were probably in middle of some rebase which you did not abort ( as indicated by the git bash prompt - `(24a2cd5...)|REBASE`). Get your working directory to a proper state and then try the merge. While the merge and add should work in a detatched head state too, I don't see any other possible problems.

Comment: No clue what I have done to get the rebase. After redoing the merge again it worked. Thanks.